# Make Dependencies of NuGet packages locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

i have a solution that have 3 c# projects , for a better undertending i will call these projects A, project B and Project C.

I want to make the project C in a NuGet packages, but these project it is on .Net Framework 4.5.1, so to do that i added other project (project D) in .Net Standart 2.0 library which make a reference to the Project C.

But when a add the NuGet package in the client project, i cant used because this project have a dependecy for Project A, B and C.

How can i do to my project C dont depend of pojects A,B and C when a make it in a Nuget Package?

Answer (score 0):

I used Nuget Package Explorer to add the three dependencies references files int the Package, and when it is installed automatically copy thats dependencies on the client project.

https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer